# Find $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\{x\}}{\{x\}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Here {$x$} denotes the fractional part of x

When $x\rightarrow0^+$, $\{x\}=x$. (Since $x$ will be a very small number example: $0.000000000001,$ it will not have an integer part, and the fractional part will be equal to the number).

When $x\rightarrow0^-$, $\{x\}=1+x$

So $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin\{x\}}{\{x\}}$ simplifies to $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

And $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\sin\{x\}}{\{x\}}$ simplifies to $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\sin (x+1)}{x+1}=\sin1$

So it's discontinuous

Edit: Made corrections as suggested in the comments

Comment: Who told you that your logic is incorrect?

Comment: @RounakSarkar, it's supposed to be a discontinuous function

Comment: I wonder what is $\{x\}$ when $x<0$, is $\{-0.4\} = -0.4$ or $0.6$?

Comment: The integral part is usually denoted with $\lfloor x\rfloor$. {$x$} could mean the fractional part. In the case that the integral part is meant the limit does not exist since for a positive $x<1$, the integer part is $0$ and the expression is not defined. And if the fractional part is meant , then the problem is that the fractional part is always positive, but the sine-term changes its sign. Again, the limit does not exist.

Comment: The following is the usual definition: $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, so for negative numbers it is not the same as "the fractional part". For example, $\lfloor-0.1\rfloor=-1$ and $\{-0.1\}=-0.1-(-1)=0.9$. In fact, $0\le\{x\}\lt 1$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \in [0,1)$ we have $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor = x-0 = x$, but for $x \in [-1,0)$ we have $\{x\} = x- \lfloor x \rfloor = x - (-1) = x+1$.